# Target specific BlackBerry's with User Agent

Tags: javascript, jquery, blackberry, browser-detection

I found this javascript to detect blackberry devices:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ua = navigator.userAgent;
    if (ua.indexOf("BlackBerry") >= 0) {
        if (ua.indexOf("Version/") >= 0) { // ***User Agent in BlackBerry 6 and BlackBerry 7
            Verposition = ua.indexOf("Version/") + 8;
            TotLenght = ua.length;
            document.write("Jorgesys  BB OS Version :: " + ua.substring(Verposition, Verposition + 3));
        }
        else {// ***User Agent in BlackBerry Device Software 4.2 to 5.0
            var SplitUA = ua.split("/");
            document.write("Jorgesys BB OS Version :: " + SplitUA[1].substring(0, 3));
        }
    }
</script>
```

BUT need to target specific BlackBerry's that are supported:

Blackberry:
9630
9700
8900
9000

Is this possible to target just those Blackberry's ??

Thank!

Comment: Did you look at the user agent and see what it contains?

Comment: BB agent strings seem to contain the data: http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/BlackBerry/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes each agent has it's blackberry version.

Example:
`**BlackBerry9000**/5.0.0.93 Profile/MIDP-2.0 Configuration/CLDC-1.1 VendorID/179`

More information on the developers website.
http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/How-to-detect-the-BlackBerry-Browser/ta-p/559862?IID=DEVSF30

use a simple regex to get the version out.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ua = "BlackBerry9000/5.0.0.93 Profile/MIDP-2.0 Configuration/CLDC-1.1 VendorID/179";
    var match = ua.match(/^BlackBerry[0-9]*/);
    console.log(match[0]);

    var ua = "Mozilla/5.0 (BlackBerry; U; BlackBerry 9700; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.11+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/X.X.X.X Mobile Safari/534.11+";
    var match = ua.match(/BlackBerry\s[0-9]*/);
    console.log(match[0]);

    var ua = "Mozilla/5.0 (PlayBook; U; RIM Tablet OS 1.0.0; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.8+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/0.0.1 Safari/534.8+";
    var match = ua.match(/RIM Tablet OS\s[0-9].[0-9].[0-9]/);
    console.log(match[0]);
</script>
```

Comment: For BB OS 6 and 7, the useragent string is different and would need to be parsed differently (your link shows both versions).

Comment: where in the code would i put that though??  i guess that is where i'm confused

Comment: @Xtian You would only be targeting Blackberry 9700, and if so just dont do the 1st check, (ua.indexOf("BlackBerry") >= 0) just do the second.